# How to convert binary in Python into bytea data type in Postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, fastapi

So I have an image which I read the contents off of through `.read()` which is part of the `UploadFile` class and I believe it reads in bytes https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/. To convert the bytes objects into `bytea` data type I used `psycopg2.Binary()` but I got an error message saying `KeyError: '$fu'`

This is my code for the portion that's reading off the bytes from the image and trying to store it in Postgresql through the `bytea` data type

```py
image_array = []
    for image in images_upload:
        contents = await image.read()
        image_array.append(contents)
    # add image validation

    for (permission, text, characteristics, image) in zip(p, c, t, image_array):

        query = ("insert into images(permissions,text,characteristics,date_created,user_id,img)"
                 f"values('{permission}','{text}',"
                 f"'{characteristics}'"
                 f",{func.now()},{result[0]['id']}"
                 f",'{psycopg2.Binary(image)}')")
        await database.execute(query=query)
```

Here's the trace

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53168 - "POST /add/?api_key=stringstring&texts=string&characteristics=string&permissions=string HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 201, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 148, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./app/controllers/add.py", line 49, in add_images
    await database.execute(query=query)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 161, in execute
    return await connection.execute(query, values)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 263, in execute
    return await self._connection.execute(built_query)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/backends/postgres.py", line 188, in execute
    query, args, result_columns = self._compile(query)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-DSfoN2Wn-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/backends/postgres.py", line 221, in _compile
    compiled_query = compiled.string % mapping
KeyError: '$fu'
```

Comment: It would be better if you included the full error trace as part of your question.

Comment: Added error trace

Comment: You are converting everything into a string, have a look at: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries **and** you are using asyncio, which isn't supported by psycopg2.

Comment: But this worked when i didnt have the binary conversion